# Is there a way to make a random number generator in java that is more likely to land on one number than another?

Tags: java, random

I want to make a random number generator in java, that generates a random number from 1-20, but I want it to be more likely to generate 1 than 20, like lower numbers are more likely to generate than higher number, is there a way to do that?

Comment: As an example-  rolling a dice is a random number.  Rolling 2 dice is also random-  but 7 is far more likely than 12.

Comment: Are you looking for a continuous or a discrete distribution?  In other words, reals in the specified range, or integers in the specified range?  Since you haven't specified any particular distribution, one simple solution would be to generate a [triangular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution) with a mode near zero.  Then use rounding, floor, or ceiling if you want integers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure.  Here's a simple way:

```
int data[] = {1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
return data[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(data.length)];
```

That will return 1 2/11 of the time, and 2-10 1/11 of the time each.  Play with the ratio by adding and removing elements.

Comment: the syntax is slightly off on this. `int[]` and `{...}`.

Comment: Yeah, been a little time since I've used the language daily.  Thanks.

Comment: @Eugene The bound for `nextInt` is exclusive, if I am not mistaken. Then `nextInt(data.length)` was fine, without the `-1`.

Comment: @Zabuzard indeed.

Comment: By the way, in Java 9+ you can use convenient literals syntax to make a list rather than an array by calling [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)): `List< Integer > data = List.of( 1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ) ;`